# SDL/OpenGL commands not set in scope?

Tags: opengl, scope, command, sdl, undefined

I'm trying to write a very simple sdl and gl program on a mac to create a triangle, but its not really working.

(in c++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>

/*INITIALIZE*/
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45,640.0/480.0,1.0,500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

/*DISPLAY*/
void display()   // drawing
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glVertex3f(0.0,2.0,-5.0);
    glVertex3f(-2.0,-2.0,-5.0);
    glVertex3f(2.0,-2.0,-5.0);

    glEnd();
}

/*MAIN*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) // arguments required
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); // initialize and setup sdl
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_OPENGL);
    bool running = true;
    Uint32 start;
    SDL_Event event;
    init();

    while (running)
    {
        start = SDL_GetTicks();

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        display();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
        if(1000/30 > (SDL_GetTicks() - start))
            SDL_Delay(1000/30 - (SDL_GetTicks() - start));
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;

}
```

But when I compile it:

```
Computer:sdlcode User$ g++ third.cpp -GL -GLU
third.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
third.cpp:34: error: ‘SDL_OPENGL’ was not declared in this scope
third.cpp:34: error: ‘SDL_SetVideoMode’ was not declared in this scope
third.cpp:55: error: ‘SDL_GL_SwapBuffers’ was not declared in this scope
Computer:sdlcode User$
```

Whats going wrong here and how do I prevent it from having further commands undeclared?

Comment: What are you assuming that `g++` is doing with the `-GL` and `-GLU` flags?  Did you mean `-lGL` and `-lGLU`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you included SDL headers through the local include statement, i.e. using double quotes instead of wedges. The compiler message indicates that something goes wrong when including `SDL/SDL.h`. Either your installation of SDL is broken, or you by accident put an empty, or mismatching SDL/SDL.h into your source directory.

In either case you must make sure that your installation of SDL is valid.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're just not linking with the SDL libraries when compiling. Just add the appropriate -l flag and it should work.

EDIT: datenwolf pointed out that the error wasn't due to missing libraries. You should still include the right libraries when you get the headers fixed, though. :)

Comment: "not declared in scope" is a compiler message, referring to missing function declarations. I.e. missing headers. The linker message would be "undefined reference".